# Phonegap CSS background not displaying on Android

Tags: html, css, cordova

I'm just starting to use phonegap and am having a problem displaying a background through both the body and a div.  The background image I am using is the same as the splash screen, and the only difference is that the splash screen loads the image, while the css won't display it.  Here is my code...

```
<style>
#bg {
background: url(_images/splash.png) top center no-repeat;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="bg">
Hi
</div>
```

I've tried adding quotes around the image url, adding and removing the "top", "center" and "no-repeat", and also tried using background-image instead of just background, but nothing is working for some odd reason.  I've managed to have a background color work, just the imaging won't work.

And since I am using dreamweaver's design view/live view, I also check to make sure the image shows up before I download the app all over again to my phone.

Comment: Did you tried to use quotes inside the url? like `url("_images/splash.png")`

Comment: Yes, I've tried both single quotes and double quotes around it.  The code I posted was the latest attempt.

Comment: Do the other style properties (height, width) work correctly?

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? The image path is relative to the CSS file (or html file, in your case)'s location

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with Android and Phonegap. What worked for me is setting the background-size and background-position with the image, like this:

```
#bg
{
     background: url(_images/splash.png) no-repeat center center;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     background-position:100% 100%;
}
```

My styles are also defined inline, I don't know think it has to do anything with the issue, but try it out.

```
<div style="background:url(uploads/front.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
            background-size: 100% 100%; 
            background-position:100% 100%;">
</div>
```

Comment: tried every thing except this, worked thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

try to put your css at the end of the page.

otherwhise, open the file inside your desktop browser (don't care about errors).
if you can see the background, it's like a bug of phonegap.
if you can't see it, you've made an error (404, the file is not existing?)

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer just by messing around with it.  I guess the underscore in the directory name was not allowing it to work.  So just in case anyone else runs into this problem, I guess avoid using underscores.

Comment: I don't get it. Isn't Android based on ordinary Linux, with ordinary filename rules like "anything goes, just avoid non-printable characters for your own peace of mind"? I can't think of a single OS where an underscore would be a problem.